# Deleting column using vba takes a huge amount of time

Tags: excel, vba

Newbie here.

I'm trying to delete a column using vba and it is taking a HUGE amount of time.

```
Sub Add_Delete()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Workbooks("f.xlsx").Sheets("g").Columns("FD:FD").EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

There are about 20,000 rows with a total of amount 230 columns. There are no calculations being performed. Just data

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume when you delete it manually it deletes quickly and isn't causing excel to bog down doing a bunch of recalculations?

Comment: There are no calculations.  Actually when I try to delete directly in excel it takes a long time, too.  Maybe nothing I can do?

Comment: At least your `Workbooks("f.xlsx").Sheets("g").Columns("FD:FD").EntireColumn.Delete` can be written as `Workbooks("f.xlsx").Sheets("g").Columns(160).Delete` and will do the same :P I don't know who started something useless like `Columns().EntireColumn` (every third post here shows obsolete coding like that)

Comment: Did you try the answer I posted?

Answer (score 0):

If it is slow manually also turn off calculation before running it, then turn it back on.

```
Sub Add_Delete()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Workbooks("f.xlsx").Sheets("g").Columns("FD:FD").EntireColumn.Delete
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

add screen updating back in also... ;-)

Comment: You need to clarify varCalcMode.  I assume that's a variable you use to store the calc mode before changing it, so you can change it back.

I believe you have the solution though: turning off auto calculation

Comment: Oops, yeah. edited it to have the right info.
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic